# How to allow a marquee tag in HTML purifier module in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, htmlpurifier

I'm using HTML purifier module in Drupal 7. I know that, marquee isn't a valid HTML tag and HTML purifier doesn't support it, but I had to use the tag because of a jQuery scroller that uses a `<marquee>` tag.

I cannot use CSS3 animations to scroll a piece of text to respect old web browsers.

So, how can I allow a marquee tag on Drupal 7 using HTML purifier?

Comment: where do you want the <marquee> tag to be displayed i.e. on node view or anywhere else?

Comment: I want it to be displayed in a block.

Comment: use hook_block_view_alter hook in your custom module to alter the content of the block and place your markup tag.